# "certains / des / quelque / quelques-uns / pas mal de" What does it all mean and in what situations it is used?

Tags: grammaire

I looked up the word "some" from the translation and I saw these. Des (à+l) the only thing I know, des (de+les) which is indefinite version of les. But what about others? I've never heard of these.

Answer (score 2):

**Certains** means some people or a few: "Certains anglais parlent Français" may translates to "Some english people speak French". Without the *s*, it indicates when someone is sure about something "J'en suis certain qu'il est fort" translates to " I am sure that he is strong".

**Quelque** is similar to **certains** but is generally more vague like Je possède quelques livres translates I own a few books.

**Quelques-uns** which is the plural form of *quelqu'un* meaning someone.

**Pas mal de** means a fair amount like Je suis allé au match et il y avait pas mal de gens translated to I went to see the game and there was a fair amount of people.

Answer (score 1):

All can translate to "some" but often with nuances:

> ***Certains*** means "some" as a subset of a group.
> *Certains ne sont pas venus.* → Some didn't show up.

> ***Des*** is the plural of *un*, some as "more than one".
> *Des garçons jouent.* → Some boys are playing

> ***Quelque*** is a singular "some", often like "any". It is literary except in some fixed expressions like *quelque chose* (something/anything), *quelque part* (somewhere), *quelqu'un* (someone/anyone).

> *C'est une chose admirable, que tous les grands hommes ont toujours du caprice, quelque petit grain de folie mêlé à leur science*, Molière, *Le médecin malgré lui*.

> It is an admirable thing, that all great men always have whims, some small touch of madness mixed with their wisdom.

> ***Quelques*** means some like "a few", "a couple", "a handful".
> *Je reviens dans quelques jours.* → I'll be back in a few days.

> ***Quelques-uns*** means some like "some of them", it is close to *certains*. Note that *quelques-uns* can refer to people, things or whatever and has a regular feminine form (*quelques-unes*) while *quelqu'un* is necessarily a person and is very rarely used at the feminine (*quelqu'une*).
> *Il y en a quelques-unes de cachées* → Some of them are hidden.

> ***Pas mal de*** is a "bigger some" like "quite a bit", "quite a lot".
> *J'ai raté pas mal de choses.* → I missed quite a lot of things.